# Building a function to calculate the series solution to this Solved Boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, finite-element-method, summation

I have the following code which solves for $(1)$ (i.e. solves for $C_1$ and $C_2$)

$$
T(x,y,z)=\sum_{n,m=0}^{\infty}(C_1 e^{\gamma z}+C_2 e^{-\gamma z})\sin\bigg(\frac{\alpha_n x}{L}+\beta_n\bigg)\sin\bigg(\frac{\delta_m y}{l}+\theta_m\bigg)+T_a \tag 1
$$

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (C1* E^(γ z) + C2 E^(- γ z))*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + Ta
tc[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUC* y/l)*{tci + (NTUC/l)*Integrate[E^(NTUC*s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]};
tc[x_, y_] = tc[x, y][[1]];
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]); 
ortheq1 = Integrate[bc1[[1]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}] == Integrate[bc1[[2]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}];
ortheq1 = ortheq1 // Simplify;
th[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUH*x/L)*{thi + (NTUH/L)*Integrate[E^(NTUH*s/L)*T[s, y, w], {s, 0, x}]};
th[x_, y_] = th[x, y][[1]];
bc2 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph (th[x, y] - T[x, y, w]);
ortheq2 = Integrate[bc2[[1]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}] == Integrate[bc2[[2]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}];
ortheq2 = ortheq2 // Simplify;
soln = Solve[{ortheq1, ortheq2}, {Subscript[C, 1], Subscript[C, 2]}];
CC1 = C1 /. soln[[1, 1]];
CC2 = C2 /. soln[[1, 2]];
expression1 := CC1;
c1[α_, β_, δ_, θ_, γ_] := Evaluate[expression1];
expression2 := CC2;
c2[α_, β_, δ_, θ_, γ_] := Evaluate[expression2];
```

The following relations hold, $\beta_n=\tan^{-1}(1.66\times10^4 \alpha_n)$ and $\delta_m=\tan^{-1}(8.33\times10^3 \theta_m)$

The `n=0` values is $\alpha_0=0.01095$ and `m=0` value is $\delta_0=0.01549$.

Subsequently from `n=1` and `m=1` it is known that $\alpha_n=n\pi$ and $\delta_m=m\pi$.

**I want to build a function such that this summation can be automatically performed for the desired values of $n$ and $m$**.

$T_a$ is added only once in the final $T(x,y,z)$. The rest of the constants along with the other functions I wish to calculate are given below:

```
L = 0.9; l = 1.8; w = 0.0003; NTUH = 17.394; NNTUC = 22.151; ph = 8.6; pc = 13.93;
γ = Sqrt[(α/L)^2 + (δ/l)^2];
thi=460;tci=300;Ta=380;
tc1[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUC* y/l)*{tci + (NTUC*/l)*Integrate[E^(NTUC* s/l)*(TWnet /. {y -> s, z -> 0}), {s, 0, y}]};
th1[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUH* x/L)*{thi + (NTUH/L)*Integrate[E^(NTUH* s/L)*(TWnet /. {x -> s, z -> w}), {s, 0, x}]};
Plot[tc1[x, l], {x, 0, L}]
Plot[th1[L, y], {y, 0, l}]
THotAvg = Integrate[th1[x, y]/l, {y, 0, l}];
TColdAvg = Integrate[tc1[x, y]/L, {x, 0, L}];
THotAvg /. x -> L
TColdAvg /. y -> l
Plot[THotAvg, {x, 0, L}]
Plot[TColdAvg, {y, 0, l}]
```

The term `TWnet` in the above code section is the final $T(x,y,z)$ function I desire. So if someone can make the final distribution as a function then terms like `TWnet /. {y -> s, z -> 0}` would be something like `TWnet[x,s,0]`

I hope I was able to clearly explain the requirements here.

NOTE: The first code section takes some time to execute

---

***CONTEXTUAL INFORMATION***

I am trying to solve $\nabla^2 T(x,y,z)=0$ defined on $x\in[0,L], y\in[0,l]$ and $z\in[0,w]$ subjected to the following boundary conditions:

$$k(\frac{\partial T(0,y,z)}{\partial x})=h_a(T(0,y,z)-T_a) \tag A$$

$$-k(\frac{\partial T(L,y,z)}{\partial x})=h_a(T(L,y,z)-T_a) \tag B$$

$$k(\frac{\partial T(x,0,z)}{\partial y})=h_a(T(x,0,z)-T_a)\tag C$$

$$-k(\frac{\partial T(x,l,z)}{\partial y})=h_a(T(x,l,z)-T_a) \tag D$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z} = p_c\bigg(T(x,y,0)-e^{-\beta_c y/l}\left[t_{ci} + \frac{\beta_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{\beta_c s/l}T(x,s,0)ds\right]\bigg) \tag E$$

$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z} = p_h\bigg(e^{-\beta_h x/L}\left[t_{hi} + \frac{\beta_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{\beta_h s/L}T(x,s,w)ds\right]-T(x,y,w)\bigg) \tag F$$

**Now under the conditions $A,B,C,D$, the solution form of the three-dimensional Laplacian is given by $(1)$**

$\gamma=\sqrt{(\alpha/L)^2 + (\delta/L)^2}$ (Have not mentioned this explicitly in the original question, so I wrote it here).

In the first section of the code I apply the $z$ boundary conditions and use orthogonality to determine the constants $C_1, C_2$. I must mention here that I have already proven the orthogonality of $\sin\bigg(\frac{\alpha_n x}{L}+\beta_n\bigg)$ under the boundary conditions $A-D$
The values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are to be calculated using the following transcendental equation:

$$2\cot{\alpha}=\frac{k\alpha}{h_a L}-\frac{h_aL}{k\alpha}\tag G$$
$$\beta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{k \alpha}{h_a L})\tag H$$

Similar set of equation exists for $\delta$ and $\theta$

**I only want solution in the limit of very small $h_a \rightarrow 0$ for which except the first $\alpha$ value all other values are $n\pi$.** I have derived an expression to calculate the first value which is:

$$\alpha=\frac 1{\sqrt a} \left( 1+\frac{1}{3 a}-\frac{8}{45 a^2}+\frac{53}{630
   a^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^4}\right)\right)$$

where $a=k/(2h_a L)$. But in any case, I have posted the numerical values in the original question.

Once I get the $T(x,y,z)$ my objective is to calculate $t_h$ and $t_c$ which are given by:

$$t_h=e^{-\beta_h x/L}\bigg(t_{hi} + \frac{\beta_h}{L}\int_0^x e^{\beta_h s/L}T(x,s,w)ds\bigg) \tag I$$

$$t_c=e^{-\beta_c y/l}\bigg(t_{ci} + \frac{\beta_c}{l}\int_0^y e^{\beta_c s/l}T(x,s,0)ds\bigg) \tag J$$

---

**Origins of the b.c.**$E,F$

Actual bc(s): $$\frac{\partial T(x,y,0)}{\partial z}=p_c (T(x,y,0)-t_c) \tag K$$
$$\frac{\partial T(x,y,w)}{\partial z}=p_h (t_h-T(x,y,w))\tag L$$

where $t_h,t_c$ are defined in the equation:

$$\frac{\partial t_c}{\partial y}+\frac{\beta_c}{l}(t_c-T(x,y,0))=0 \tag M$$
$$\frac{\partial t_h}{\partial x}+\frac{\beta_h}{L}(t_h-T(x,y,0))=0 \tag N$$

It is known that $t_h(x=0)=t_{hi}$ and $t_c(y=0)=t_{ci}$. I had solved $M,N$ using the method of integrating factors and used the given conditions to reach $I,J$ which were then substituted into the original b.c.(s) $K,L$ to reach $E,F$.

---

**My attempt**
I have written the following script to carry out the summation:

```
γ[α_, δ_] = Sqrt[(α/L)^2 + (δ/l)^2];
L = 0.9; l = 1.8; w = 0.0003; NTUH = 17.394; NTUC = 22.151; ph = 8.6; pc = 13.93;
α0 = 0.01095439637; δ0 = 0.0154917784; β0 = 1.56532; θ0 = 1.56305;
thi = 460; tci = 300; Ta = 380;
V0 = ((c1[α0, β0, δ0, θ0, γ[α0, δ0]] *E^(γ[α0, δ0] *z) + c2[α0, β0, δ0, θ0, γ[α0, δ0]]* E^(-γ[α0, δ0] *z))*Sin[δ0*y/l + θ0] + Sum[(c1[α0, β0, m*\[Pi], 1.5708,γ[α0, m*\[Pi]]] *E^(γ[α0, m*\[Pi]] *z) + c2[α0, β0, m*\[Pi], 1.5708, γ[α0, m*\[Pi]]]*E^(-γ[α0, m*\[Pi]]* z))*Sin[m*\[Pi]*y/l + 1.5708], {m, 1, 5}])*Sin[α0*x/L + β0];
Vn = Sum[((c1[n*\[Pi], 1.5708, δ0, θ0, γ[n*\[Pi], δ0]] *E^(γ[n*\[Pi], δ0] *z) + c2[n*\[Pi], 1.5708, δ0, θ0, γ[n*\[Pi], δ0]]* E^(-γ[n*\[Pi], δ0]* z))*Sin[δ0*y/l + θ0] + Sum[(c1[n*\[Pi], 1.5708, m*\[Pi], 1.5708, γ[n*\[Pi], m*\[Pi]]] *E^(γ[n*\[Pi], m*\[Pi]] *z) + c2[n*\[Pi], 1.5708, m*\[Pi], 1.5708, γ[n*\[Pi], m*\[Pi]]]* E^(-γ[n*\[Pi], m*\[Pi]]* z))*Sin[m*\[Pi]*y/l + 1.5708], {m, 1, 5}])*Sin[n*\[Pi]*x/L +1.5708], {n, 1, 5}];
Vnet = V0 + Vn + Ta;
tcf[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUC* y/l)*{tci + (NTUC/l)*Integrate[E^(NTUC* s/l)*(Vnet /. {y -> s, z -> 0}), {s, 0, y}]};
thf[x_, y_] = E^(-NTUH* x/L)*{thi + (NTUH/L)*Integrate[E^(NTUH* s/L)*(Vnet /. {x -> s, z -> w}), {s, 0, x}]};
tcfavg = Integrate[tcf[x, y], {x, 0, L}]/L;
thfavg = Integrate[thf[x, y], {y, 0, l}]/l;
tcfavg /. y -> l // Chop
thfavg /. x -> L // Chop
```

The `tcfavg` and `thfavg` plots i get are also weird
[image: tcfavg]
[image: thfavg]
And the outlet temperatures are

```
tcfavg /. y -> l // Chop
401.984
thfavg /. x -> L // Chop
344.348
```

Comment: Your T function is on the left hand side dependent on `{x,y,z}` but on the right hand side not a `y`.

Comment: @user2432923 Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected now.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I can understand the frustration on seeing such code. But actually inside mathematica I used $c_1$, but whenever I copy and paste it  here on MMA SE, it changes to these expanded notations. Even Greek letters would become `\beta`. Apologies for this inconvenience. But I have observed that when this code is copied from here to MMA, it is interpreted correctly

Comment: @IndrasisMitra It looks like you try to solve 3D Laplace equation with Dirichlet  boundary condition?

Comment: @AlexTrounev It is the 3D Laplace equation but with similar Robin boundaries on $z$ coordinate and a set of similar Robin conditions on the $x,y$ direction. If it helps should I post the full set of equations that describe the problem ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Yes, please, post equations too.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Have added a context section describing the origin of the question.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Did you get the chance to look at the equations I posted ? Please let me know if there is more information I could provide that might help.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Condition `E` not so clear, but with `E` problem becomes unsolvable with `NDSolve`.  Your method is very straight, but it takes a time.

Comment: @AlexTrounev My objective is to solve this problem analytically. I have added another section to my original post explaining how the b.c.(s) $E,F$ were derived. Maybe that will clear things up a bit. Nevertheless, my original question aimed to find a mathematica routine that could help me in carrying out the double summation in $1$ with the conditions that I mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need some numerical model for comparison, so this is one of them based on FEM. First we make sufficient mesh for this problem:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];Needs["MeshTools`"];
 L = .90; l = 1.80; w = 0.0003; bh = 17.394;
bc = 22.151; ph = 8.6;
pc = 13.93; pa = 10; n = 10;
thi = 460; tci = 300; Ta = 380; region = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {L, l}];
mesh2D = ToElementMesh[region, MaxCellMeasure -> 5 10^-3 , 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh3D = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, w, 5];
mesh = HexToTetrahedronMesh[mesh3D];

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

Now we solve the problem by iteration. I have optimized this code, thus it takes about 5 sec:

```
TC[x_, y_] := tci; TH[x_, y_] := thi;
Do[U[i] = 
  NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
     NeumannValue[-pa (u[x, y, z] - 
          Ta) , (x == 0 || x == L || y == 0 || y == l) & 0 <= z <= 
        w] + NeumannValue[-pc (u[x, y, z] - TC[x, y]), z == 0] + 
      NeumannValue[-ph (u[x, y, z] - TH[x, y]), z == w]}, 
   u, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
 tc[i] = ParametricNDSolveValue[{t'[y] + 
      bc/l (t[y] - U[i][x, y, 0]) == 0, t[0] == tci}, 
   t, {y, 0, l}, {x}]; 
 th[i] = ParametricNDSolveValue[{t'[x] + 
      bh/L (t[x] - U[i][x, y, w]) == 0, t[0] == thi}, 
   t, {x, 0, L}, {y}]; 
 TC = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, tc[i][x][y]}, {x, 0, L, .02 L}, {y, 0, l, 
      0.02 l}], 1]]; 
 TH = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, th[i][y][x]}, {x, 0, L, .02 L}, {y, 0, l, 
      0.02 l}], 1]];, {i, 1, n}]
```

Now we can visualize numerical solution for `tc,th` in 2 points on every iteration to check how fast solution converges:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[tc[i][L][y], {i, 1, n}]], {y, 0, l}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"y", "tc(L,y)"}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[th[i][l][x], {i, 1, n}]], {x, 0, L}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "th(x,l)"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
We see that solution converges fast in 10 steps. Now we can visualize `T` in 3 slice on `z` and `tc, th` on the last iteration

```
{DensityPlot[U[n][x, y, 0], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 DensityPlot[U[n][x, y, w/2], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 DensityPlot[U[n][x, y, w], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All]}

{DensityPlot[TC[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "tc"], 
 DensityPlot[TH[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "th"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally we calculate average temperature

```
tcoldAv = NIntegrate[TC[x, l], {x, 0, L}]/L

Out[]= 381.931

thotAv = NIntegrate[TH[L, y], {y, 0, l}]/l

Out[]= 377.481
```

Now we can try to improve code for analytical solution. First part of code I just take as it is, but delete two lines and extend number of parameters of functions `c1,c2` :

```
T[x_, y_, 
  z_] = (C1*E^(\[Gamma] z) + C2 E^(-\[Gamma] z))*
   Sin[(\[Alpha] x/L) + \[Beta]]*Sin[(\[Delta] y/l) + \[Theta]] + Ta
tc[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-NTUC*y/l)*{tci + (NTUC/l)*
      Integrate[E^(NTUC*s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]};
(*tc[x_,y_]=tc[x,y][[1]];*)
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == pc (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]);
ortheq1 = 
  Integrate[(bc1[[1]] - bc1[[2]])*Sin[(\[Alpha] x/L) + \[Beta]]*
     Sin[(\[Delta] y/l) + \[Theta]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
    Assumptions -> {C1 > 0, C2 > 0, L > 0, 
      l > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Delta] > 
       0, \[Theta] > 0, NTUC > 0, pc > 0, Ta > 0, tci > 0}] == 0;
(*ortheq1=ortheq1//Simplify;*)
th[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-NTUH*x/L)*{thi + (NTUH/L)*
      Integrate[E^(NTUH*s/L)*T[s, y, w], {s, 0, x}]};
(*th[x_,y_]=th[x,y][[1]];*)
bc2 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == ph (th[x, y] - T[x, y, w]);
ortheq2 = 
  Integrate[(bc2[[1]] - bc2[[2]])*Sin[(\[Alpha] x/L) + \[Beta]]*
     Sin[(\[Delta] y/l) + \[Theta]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
    Assumptions -> {C1 > 0, C2 > 0, L > 0, 
      l > 0, \[Alpha] > 0, \[Beta] > 0, \[Gamma] > 0, \[Delta] > 
       0, \[Theta] > 0, NTUC > 0, pc > 0, Ta > 0, thi > 0}] == 0;
(*ortheq2=ortheq2//Simplify;*)
soln = Solve[{ortheq1, ortheq2}, {C1, C2}];
CC1 = C1 /. soln[[1, 1]];
CC2 = C2 /. soln[[1, 2]];
expression1 := CC1;
c1[α_, β_, δ_, θ_, γ_, L_, l_, NTUC_, pc_, Ta_, tci_, NTUH_, ph_, thi_, w_] := Evaluate[expression1];
expression2 := CC2;
c2[α_, β_, δ_, θ_, γ_, L_, l_, NTUC_, pc_, Ta_, tci_, NTUH_, ph_, thi_, w_] := Evaluate[expression2];
```

Now we run the very fast code for numerical solution

```
 \[Gamma]1[\[Alpha]_, \[Delta]_] := 
 Sqrt[(\[Alpha]/L)^2 + (\[Delta]/l)^2]; m0 = 30; n0 = 30;
L = 0.9; l = 1.8; w = 0.0003; NTUH = 17.394; NTUC = 22.151; ph = 8.6; \
pc = 13.93;
\[Alpha]0 = 0.01095439637; \[Delta]0 = 0.0154917784; \[Beta]0 = \
1.56532; \[Theta]0 = 1.56305;
thi = 460; tci = 300; Ta = 380;
b[n_] := Evaluate[ArcTan[1.66 10^4 (\[Alpha]0 + n Pi)]];
tt[m_] := Evaluate[ArcTan[8.33 10^3 (\[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi])]];
Vn = Sum[(c1[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], b[n], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi], 
        tt[m], \[Gamma]1[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi]], L,
         l, pc, pc, Ta, tci, ph, ph, thi, w]*
       E^(\[Gamma]1[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi]]*z) + 
      c2[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], b[n], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi], 
        tt[m], \[Gamma]1[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi]], L,
         l, pc, pc, Ta, tci, ph, ph, thi, w]*
       E^(-\[Gamma]1[\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi], \[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi]]*z))*
    Sin[(\[Delta]0 + m*\[Pi])*y/l + tt[m]]*
    Sin[(\[Alpha]0 + n*\[Pi])*x/L + b[n]], {n, 0, n0}, {m, 0, m0}];
Vnet = Vn/2 + Ta;

tc = ParametricNDSolveValue[{t'[y] + pc/l (t[y] - Vnet /. z -> 0) == 
    0, t[0] == tci}, t, {y, 0, l}, {x}]; th = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{t'[x] + ph/L (t[x] - Vnet /. z -> w) == 0, 
   t[0] == thi}, t, {x, 0, L}, {y}]; TC = 
 Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, tc[x][y]}, {x, 0, L, .01 L}, {y, 0, l, 
     0.01 l}], 1]]; TH = 
 Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, th[y][x]}, {x, 0, L, .01 L}, {y, 0, l, 
     0.01 l}], 1]];
```

Note, I am using `Vn/2` to limit low and high temperature. And finally we visualize solution

```
{DensityPlot[TC[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "tc"], 
 DensityPlot[TH[x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> "th"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Really appreciate this effort. Thanks. From the time the last answer (by Steffen) was posted on this question, I have managed to write a script to carry out the summation $(1)$.Should I post the code here if you would like to take a look ?

Comment: I have posted my code to sum $(1)$ as an edit to the original question. I do not know why but the average temperatures I get are far off. If you are interested further I will post the equations to the `V0,Vn` terms in my code. NOTE: The term `bh,bc` in your code is `NTUH,NTUC` in mine.Also the functions `c1,c2` defined in the attempt come from the first code section which I have edited now to reflect these definitions.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Could you please post parameter $h_a$? I put it as `pa=10`.

Comment: The $h_a$ value is $0.001$. I executed your code for this. The results are `tcoldAv=383.65, thotAv=348.34`. Another concern for me is the nature of the cold and hot average plots. My `tcfavg` shows a dip first, similarly `thfavg` shows a rise at the start. This is un-physical behavior as the cold fluid temperature should only rise and the hot fluid should only decrease. These discrepancies are not present in your solution.

Comment: Intersetingly when I consider a miniaturized heat exchanger (these equations represent a corss-flow heat exchanger) with values as `L=l=0.025, w=0.003,ha=0.001,bh=bc=0.487,ph=pc=54.2,thi=100,tci=20, Ta=60` the results i get from my analytical solution and the code are `thfavg=85.37, tcfavg=34.63` and the results from your FEM solution (I refined the mesh size) is `thotAv=85.42, tcoldAv=34.57` which seems to be a pretty good match. In these dimensions, I don't get the anomalies I mentioned before and even the profiles match.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra  It is very good for your solution. We will check why there are discrepancies when different scale. We need to put `n=40` for $h_a=0.001$

Comment: I was not able to figure out why my code fails when the device is scaled up. However, your answer has enabled me with a benchmark to cross-check my own analytical solution. Hence, I award you the bounty.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Thank you! What is the reason for divergence analytical solution when scaled up? It looks like  we need increase upper limit in Vn=Sum[....{n,1,nn}] up to 10.

Comment: I did try till `n=5,m=5` terms but had no improvements. Since I am locked down in my home these days due to the pandemic, I do not have access to my desktop and am performing these calculations on a laptop. Increasing beyond $5$ terms, the calculation never completes.

Comment: didn't check this post lately so was unaware of the edit. Will go through it now.

Comment: Some of the things i noticed: with your modifications, the first section of the code is much faster than my version. Even the constants $C1$ and $C2$ are relatively smaller in size when simplified. This is really helpful.

Comment: Regarding the second section, I see that for fluid temperatures you use a numerical approach by substituting the analytically obtained wall temperature. I have two observations regarding this: A) While calculating `Vn` you use $\delta_0+m\pi$ and $\alpha_0+n\pi$ as arguments which are a neat trick to overcome the separate summations I was performing and also speeds up the code.  Am i right ? B) While calculating `Vnet` you use `Vn/2`, can you please elaborate on this decision ? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @IndrasisMitra Code been speed up due to replacement of symbolic `Integrate` with numerical `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: One final question. Why did you use `Vn/2` instead of `Vn`? Is it some normalization ?

Comment: @IndrasisMitra This normalization is due to definition of `c1,c2`. Please, check how you get this coefficients.

Answer (score 5):

Your T function is on the left-hand side dependent on `{x,y,z}` but on the right-hand side not a `y` in the MathML code. You got confused by the name of the functions in special states of the solutions process and forget to use them consequently. The solution of the Subscript[C,1], Subscript[C,2] depends in length on the given parameters but all are not set in the definitions above. It is a deviation from the solution path not to name the solution special at the end of the first Mathematica code section.

```
T[x_, y_, z_] = (Subscript[C, 1] E^(γ z) + Subscript[C, 2] E^(- γ z))*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + Subscript[T, a]
tc[x_, y_] = E^(-Subscript[β, c] y/l)*{tci + (Subscript[β, c]/l)*Integrate[E^(Subscript[β, c] s/l)*T[x, s, 0], {s, 0, y}]};
tc[x_, y_] = tc[x, y][[1]];
bc1 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> 0) == Subscript[p, c] (T[x, y, 0] - tc[x, y]); 
ortheq1 = Integrate[bc1[[1]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}] == Integrate[bc1[[2]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}];
ortheq1 = ortheq1 // Simplify;
th[x_, y_] = E^(-Subscript[β, h] x/L)*{thi + (Subscript[β, h]/L)*Integrate[E^(Subscript[β, h] s/L)*T[s, y, w], {s, 0, x}]};
th[x_, y_] = th[x, y][[1]];
bc2 = (D[T[x, y, z], z] /. z -> w) == Subscript[p, h] (th[x, y] - T[x, y, w]);
ortheq2 = Integrate[bc2[[1]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}] == Integrate[bc2[[2]]*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, l}];
ortheq2 = ortheq2 // Simplify;
soln = Solve[{ortheq1, ortheq2}, {Subscript[C, 1], Subscript[C, 2]}];
Subscript[Csol, 1] = Subscript[C, 1] /. soln[[1, 1]];
Subscript[Csol, 2] = Subscript[C, 2] /. soln[[1, 2]];
```

From that plug into the definition:

```
Tsol[x_, y_, z_] = (Subscript[Csol, 1] E^(γ z) + Subscript[Csol, 2] E^(- γ z))*Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + Subscript[T, a]
```

This Tsol is Your Twnet the variables and parameters plugged in correctly.

It is much better to define:

`T[x_, y_, z_,γ_,α_,β_,δ_,θ_,L_,l_,Subscript[T_, a]]`

so that another source of confusion. Might be a good idea to name such complicated variable parameters as `Subscript[T_, a]` shorter such as `T_`.

Doing so the second part of Your Mathematica code does take a long time too.

```
α = 0.01095; δ = 0.1549;
β = ArcTan[1.66*10^4 α]; θ = 
 Tan[δ/(10^3 * 8.33)];

TWnet = (Subscript[Csol, 1] E^(γ z) + 
      Subscript[Csol, 2] E^(-γ z))*
    Sin[(α x/L) + β]*Sin[(δ y/l) + θ] + 
   Subscript[T, a];


L = 0.9; l = 1.8; w = 0.0003; Subscript[β, h] = 17.394; 
Subscript[β, c] = 22.151; Subscript[p, h] = 8.6; 
Subscript[p, c] = 13.93;
γ = Sqrt[(α/L)^2 + (δ/l)^2];
thi = 460; tci = 300; Subscript[T, a] = 380;
tc1[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-Subscript[β, c] y/l)*{tci + (Subscript[β, c]/l)*
      Integrate[
       E^(Subscript[β, c] s/l)*(TWnet /. {y -> s, z -> 0}), {s, 
        0, y}]};
th1[x_, y_] = 
  E^(-Subscript[β, h] x/L)*{thi + (Subscript[β, h]/L)*
      Integrate[
       E^(Subscript[β, h] s/L)*(TWnet /. {x -> s, z -> w}), {s, 
        0, x}]};
Plot[tc1[x, l], {x, 0, L}]
Plot[th1[L, y], {y, 0, l}]
THotAvg = Integrate[th1[x, y]/l, {y, 0, l}];
TColdAvg = Integrate[tc1[x, y]/L, {x, 0, L}];
THotAvg /. x -> L
TColdAvg /. y -> l
Plot[THotAvg, {x, 0, L}]
Plot[TColdAvg, {y, 0, l}]
```

[image: Graphics]

[image: Graphics]

```
{408.044}

{433.444}
```

[image: Graphics]

[image: Graphics]

This is as close stuck to the given information and independent of n and m.

A start is

nmax = 3; mmax = 3;

```
T[x_, y_, z_,γ_,α_,β_,δ_,θ_,L_,l_,Subscript[T_, a]] = 
 Sum[(Subscript[C, 1] E^(γ z) + 
      Subscript[C, 2] E^(-γ z))*
    Sin[(Subscript[α, n] x/L) + Subscript[β, n]]*
    Sin[(Subscript[δ, m] y/l) + Subscript[θ, m]] + 
   Subscript[T, a], {n, 0, nmax}, {m, 0, mmax}]
```

And solve for each n and m.

Comment: How long this code run?

Comment: @user2432923 Thanks for this. But as I have said in the original question $\alpha_0, \delta_0$ are the values that I want to supply. From here i.e. `n=1`  the subsequent values are defined by $\alpha=n\pi$ and $\delta=m\pi$. This has not been probably used in your answer or am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I did not time that, but it was about an hour, just the first part of the code. The second worked fast after inserting the values for the coefficients.

Comment: @Indrasis Mitra: I am the opinion that this will take me a too long time. Such Fourier Expansions are usually convergent very rapidly, so it suffices to make a plot of the amplitude functions c1 and c2 that are not dependent on the expansion parameter n and m or Your T function have to be corrected for that dependencies.